# label text in ios with more brigtness

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m creating an image gallery with  label on top of it where the label background is opaque.i was successful in placing the text above the label.the problem is textcolor is not bright enough.my text color is white..but it lacking the brightness which is required could u guys help me out below is the code.

```
    label=[[UILabel alloc]init];

    label.frame = CGRectMake(column*248, row*175+415, 242, 70);
    label.text=[story objectAtIndex:i];
    label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:21];
    label.alpha=0.5;
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    //label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.numberOfLines=2;
    [view1 addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alpha value for the entire label is 0.5. This also dampens the font color. You could simply set the background of the label to a color with alpha value 0.5, the text should still be alpha 1.0 then.

```
label.alpha = 1.0;  // is already the default
label.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];
```

Comment: so u mean increase the text alpha to 1.0

Comment: thanks that totally worked...one more help..when i assign my text in the label.the text starts from the very begging of the label what i want is a small space at the very beggining and then the text

Comment: Either you insert a space each time programmatically; or you have your label be a subview of a separate `UIView`; or you go the messy route to manipulate the label's internal drawing routines.